# How can I change a mask's color?

Tags: payday-2

I've got masks and colors, but can't find how to change a mask color.  When I preview it, it appears white...

Is it a bug of the preview mode, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so first of all, a color and a mask are not the only ingredients to create a custom mask:

> A custom mask consists of a form, a color scheme, a pattern, and a material.

Also, from what I've seen so far, the color only applies to the pattern you use during the craf, which explains why my mask was remaining white with a simple colored pattern at the top of it.

For a complete list of masks, patterns and colors, you can check out [this wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Masks_%28Payday_2%29).

Answer (score -2):

Firstly select the mask then select your patern but it resets right? Dont worry. Just selct the colour and it should all appear in place. Now you can test all those weird shit that you wanted.

Answer (score -3):

Go to safe house bad to your masks and you can do it there